# Error when printing results of SELECT FROM WHERE with PHP variable

Tags: php, mysql

```
EDIT: I had a typo in my original post....the issue is a bit more complicated...i had a variable passed in not a raw string.
```

I want to print out stories from a mysql database that are specific to a certain person:
so i have code that is similar to:

```
$stuff ="jamie"
    $query = "SELECT * FROM person_stories WHERE person =$stuff";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die ("didnt work");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "<a href = 'PersonStoryPage.php?pid=$row[id]'>" .$row['title']. " </a>";
    }
```

I keep on getting "didnt work" ...I know that my table `person_stories` is empty but is this the same thing as an error? The table will obviously not always be empty so I need to be able to use this block of code to go about business.

Help is appreciated!

EDIT 2: The actual error is:

```
Unknown column 'jamie' in 'where clause'
```

This is bizzare since it shouldn't be interpreting `jamie` as the column!

Comment: Try `or die (mysql_error())`!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't put single quotes around `jamie`. Try this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM person_stories WHERE person = 'jamie'"
```

### Edit:

I see the post has been edited. It should now change from this:

```
$stuff ="jamie"
$query = "SELECT * FROM person_stories WHERE person =$stuff";
```

to something like this:

```
$stuff ="jamie"
$query = "SELECT * FROM person_stories WHERE person='" . mysql_real_escape_string($stuff) . "'";
```

This will not only solve your SQL syntax error, but also protect your app from a nasty SQL injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 3):

You need to quote the criteria value for the person field (notice apostrophes around jamie):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM person_stories WHERE person = 'jamie'";
```

**Edit:**

Updated to match your update.  If you use variables that may come from user input, then you will want to use `mysql_real_escape_string` to escape the value properly for the SQL query (helps prevent SQL injection).

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM person_stories WHERE person = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($stuff) . "'";
```

Answer (score 3):

If you comparing with string, you have to enclose it with ''

try change

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM person_stories WHERE person =jamie";
```

to

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM person_stories WHERE person = 'jamie'";
```

and in my opinion, is better to modify this line:

```
echo "<a href = 'PersonStoryPage.php?pid=$row[id]'>" .$row['title']. " </a>";
```

to

```
echo "<a href = 'PersonStoryPage.php?pid=".$row['id']."'>" .$row['title']. " </a>";
```

Comment: Careful. You've got an XSS vulnerability in the link tag code. It should actually be `echo '<a href="PersonStoryPage.php?pid=' . htmlspecialchars($row['id']) . '">' . htmlspecialchars($row['title']) . '</a>';`

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your query. You are missing double quotes new jamie
try this

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM person_stories WHERE person ="jamie"';
```